# Calculated measures in MDX not working

Tags: ssas, mdx

I wanted to have results something like this:

**city       zip        revenue        x**

A        |    1     |      2000    |     10000

A     |      2      |     3000     |    10000

A      |     3     |      5000     |    10000

B      |     6      |     1500     |    3000

B     |      9      |     1500      |   3000

To get the results, I wrote this mdx statement, but **revenue** and **X** are coming out same. I thought the revenue would be aggregated over city only and for each zip the value would be the same because the city associated with the zip is same.  I wonder if any body can help me out here.

with member [Measures].[X] as
'([Location].[City].currentmember, [Measures].[Revenue])'

SELECT NON EMPTY {  Measures.[Revenue], [Measures].[X]} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Location].[City].[City]*[Location].[zip].[zip] ) }  ON ROWS FROM  [State Revenue]))

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify explicitly that you need the aggregated total for the zip code. Try adding the DefaultMember of the [zip] hierarchy in the tuple, as follows:

```
with member [Measures].[X] as '([Location].[City].currentmember, [Location].[Zip].DefaultMember, [Measures].[Revenue])'

SELECT NON EMPTY { Measures.[Revenue], [Measures].[X]} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Location].[City].[City]*[Location].[zip].[zip] ) } ON ROWS FROM [State Revenue]))
```

The DefaultMember function represents the (All) member unless specified otherwise.